# How to test a crystal with multimeter

Tags: multimeter, crystal

I have a PCB in which I need to change the crystal. I don't have scope right now with me. So is there any way I can check if the crystal is working or not after soldering it in PCB. I am not good in soldering so I thought there might be some way of checking the crystal so that to confirm that it is soldered correct and working fine. I have this [Fluke Multimeter](http://www.fluke.com/fluke/inen/digital-multimeters/general-purpose-multimeters/fluke-17b+.htm?pid=78682)

Thanks

Comment: If you have multi-meter, check continuity of crystal pad wrt respective IC pin. While supply is ON,you can check voltage at crystal pins ( is it varyng or not ).

Comment: yes its also a way to test. Thanks. But I am using a `PIC32` and it has very small pins. How to test with them.

Comment: Can your meter measure frequency, and does the frequency of the crystal fall in it's range?

Comment: @Dave My multimeter can only read frequency between 10Hz-100KHZ and I am using  8MHZ

Answer (score 1):

Make a half wave voltage doubler from a couple of 1N4148 and a couple of 1nF caps. Now connect the AC input terminal to the chrystal and connect the DVM to the DC terminals.If you have oscillation you will see something like several volts on the DVM .If the rock is dead you will see nothing.